# Smooth GMSPolyline in iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using Google Maps iOS SDK. When I draw a GMSPolyline in map, it does not look smooth. How can I make a smoother GMSPolyline or a smoother line between two coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I was using 1px stroke-width of line. Instead now I am using 4px stroke-width and its smoother.