# How to draw GMSPolyline slowly and smoothly in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps, animation

I'm able to draw GMSPolyline on GoogleMaps with array of locations like this

```
GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];

    for (int i = 0; i <anotherArray.count; i++) {

        NSString *string1 = [anotherArray2 objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *string2 = [anotherArray objectAtIndex:i];
        [path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(string1.doubleValue,string2.doubleValue)];
    }

        GMSPolyline *rectangle = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
        rectangle.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        rectangle.map = mapView_;
        rectangle.strokeWidth = 2.0f;
```

But the locations I'm getting from backend server.

So I have to refresh every 10 seconds,getting new locations and adding it to existing path. These are all working fine.

But when I am adding new locations to existing path is moving very fast.

Cause I have a GMSMarker at starting of path and it is looking like jumping from one place to another place.

So how can I animate GMSMarker like slowly moving from one place to another place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check on this [tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/google-maps-api-tutorial/). It states how to draw the route lines on the map using the `GMSPolyline` class. From this [related SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19115293/how-to-smoothly-move-gmsmarker-along-coordinates-in-objective-c):

> Change your else block to be something more like this:
>
> ```
> [CATransaction begin];
> [CATransaction setAnimationDuration:2.0];
> marker.position = coordindates;
> [CATransaction commit];
> ```
>
> We enable you to use [Core
>   Animation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coreanimation_guide/introduction/introduction.html)
>   for animating Google Maps.
>
> For a worked sample, please see
>   `AnimatedCurrentLocationViewController.{c,m}` in the SDK sample
>   application.

Also based from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18095437/smooth-gmspolyline-in-ios),  avoid using 1px stroke-width of line. Instead, use 4px stroke-width. You can also check on this [GitHub sample](https://github.com/epv44/Google-Maps-Prototype).

Comment: Thanks for detail clarification.let me check